# When doing up a quote, do I see my client in person, or send it via email?

Tags: business, freelancing, contract

Client need something done, I need to write up a quote, how do I approach it?  If you have any general strategy on this issue would also be appreciated.  This is to build a website/database for a few grand.

Comment: Who is the client? I'd be glad to call him and ask which he'd prefer.

Comment: Haha, that's funny, but I can't really do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the situation and the factors involved.

If its a simple project that won't take much time or cost much money and they aren't down the street - go ahead and email, though I would definitely follow it up with a phone call. This adds a human element to your business and makes them more comfortable with you as a contractor.

However, if this is a substantial project and they aren't unreasonably far away (I drove an hour the other day to meet a potential client), get out of your chair and drive over there! You're trying to establish a business relationship and nothing smacks of a relationship better than **meeting them face to face and shaking their hand**.

**90% of communication is non-verbal**. Always remember that.

Comment: Where "90% of communication is non-verbal" comes from?

Answer (score 0):

**I would call up the client**, introduce yourself and ask a couple more questions to get a more detailed picture of their requirments. Even if you dont really need to it gives the impression of a personalised and proffesional service. I would then gauge by their reaction how to proceeded. (email or face to face)

Generally you don't have a client meeting before the quote is accepted but that varies hugely on circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Write up a quote following this pattern:

1. Always start by introducing yourself, what your company (or yourself) does, and what you can do for your prospective client.
2. Define a problem, the customers' need to be satisfied.
3. Propose a solution.
4. Determine costs.
5. Define **terms**: payment, deliverables, whats included, whats not (support, etc.) and be clear about it.
6. Contact info.

Then send it by email in PDF format. Personal contact for quote delivery is not necessary, unless you are pithcing an idea (client isn't sure of what he wants).